# Storing PostgreSQL/PostGIS "geometry(MultiPolygon)" data type in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, postgis, mapserver, postgresql-9.2

I need to store PostgreSQL's geometry(MultiPolygon) type variable into a java variable
this is because im trying to add the geometry column to a non-spatial table for querying a map using mapserver

i tried to store it in a String which caused an error.

Please suggest me a data type in Java so that i can store the value in the geometry column of a spatial database.

here is my code snippet :

```
    String query="select geom from apmandal where mandalname='"+mname+"'";
    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(query);
    rs.next();
    Geometry geomval=rs.getXXX();
```

please suggest a getXXX() method so that i can retrieve the geometry column value

Thanks in advance

**Edit from comment:**

```
String query = "select geom from apmandal order by area desc;"; 
ResultSet rs = st0.executeQuery(query); 
rs.next(); 
String geomval = rs.getString(1).toString(); 
String newquery = "insert into test(mname, geom) values('ZAHEERABAD','"+geomval+"');"; 
int tel = st1.executeUpdate(newquery); 
System.out.println("inserted "+tel+" record");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply cast to `text` representation:

```
String query="select geom::text from apmandal where mandalname='"+mname+"'";
```

Then you can treat it just like any other text.
I quote the [PostGIS manual here](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/reference.html#PostGIS_Types):

> At least as of PostgreSQL 8.3 - Everything can be CAST to text
>   (presumably because of the magical unknown type), so no defined CASTS
>   for that need to be present for you to CAST an object to text.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Erwin!! i just figured that out and came back to notify.. i implemented it Java directly.. my code goes as follows </br>        `query="select geom from apmandal order by area desc;";`
        `ResultSet rs=st0.executeQuery(query);`
        `rs.next();`
        `String geomval=rs.getString(1).toString();`
        
        `String newquery="insert into test(mname,geom) values('ZAHEERABAD','"+geomval+"');";`
        `int tel=st1.executeUpdate(newquery);`
        `System.out.println("inserted   "+tel+"   record");`      now i have learnt new query from you.. thanks a lot :)